# Setting properties programmatically

Tags: python, properties, setter

## Question

I want to accomplish the following:

```
tmp = do_stuff(tmp2)
if tmp != None:
    num = tmp
```

However the variables to be assigned in my problem are variables (better: properties) of an object instance:

```
class mycls(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__a, self._b, self.c = 2, 3, 5
    def set_a(self, val): self.__a = val
    def set_b(self, val): self._b = val
    def set_c(self, val): self.c = val
    A = property(fset = set_a)
    B = property(fset = set_b)
    C = property(fset = set_c)
tmp2 = [7, 11, 13]
inst = mycls()
tmp = do_stuff(tmp2[0])
if tmp != None: inst.A = tmp
tmp = do_stuff(tmp2[1])
if tmp != None: inst.B = tmp
tmp = do_stuff(tmp2[2])
if tmp != None: inst.C = tmp
```

Obviously the last part looks highly repetitive and in my case needs to be applied to over 10 variables. My question now is: *how can those last 6 lines be compressed?*

## Own attempts at solving the problem

Ideally I would prefer a solution like:

```
for i in [[inst.A, 0], [inst.B, 1], [inst.C, 2]]:
    tmp = do_stuff(tmp2[i[1]])
    if tmp != None: i[0] = tmp
```

However this doesn't work (because the `inst.X` are evaluated and you can't store primitive datatypes by reference/pointer). Another approach I came up with was to use the variable names as strings and fiddle with `inst.__dict__`, e.g. like this:

```
for i in [["A", 0], ["B", 1], ["C", 2]]:
    tmp = do_stuff(tmp2[i[1]])
    if tmp != None: inst.__dict__[i[0]] = tmp
```

However this plan was foiled by the fact that `A`, `B` and `C` are properties.

LISP-like macros would be an enormous help here, unfortunately Python doesn't seem to support macros and I don't want to add dependencies to one of the macro libraries for Python I found on-line (which I didn't test since I won't be able to use them anyway).

I also want to avoid using anonymous functions in a list since this will likely result in the same amount of code as in the second code listing.

My last resort to solve this problem would currently be `eval`s, which I wanted to avoid at all cost.

Comment: Why not use lambda functions?

Comment: @Peter Kirby: my goal is to reduce the amount of code, not just transform it into a different form. In the case I misunderstood, please clarify.

Comment: I did misunderstand, sorry. However, Martjin's answer is correct, and should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for [`setattr()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#setattr):

```
for i in [["A", 0], ["B", 1], ["C", 2]]:
    tmp = do_stuff(tmp2[i[1]])
    if tmp != None: setattr(inst, i[0], tmp)
```

To quote the documentation:

> This is the counterpart of [`getattr()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr). The arguments are an object, a string and an arbitrary value. The string may name an existing attribute or a new attribute. The function assigns the value to the attribute, provided the object allows it. For example, `setattr(x, 'foobar', 123)` is equivalent to `x.foobar = 123`.

Note that since `None` is a singleton in python, usually one tests for it using the `is` or `is not` operators:

```
for i in [["A", 0], ["B", 1], ["C", 2]]:
    tmp = do_stuff(tmp2[i[1]])
    if tmp is not None:
        setattr(inst, i[0], tmp)
```

and the [PEP 8 python styleguide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) discourages compound statements; keep the `if` suite on it's own line, even if it is just one line.

Comment: Considering the styleguide comments regarding indentation: When writing example code, I try to keep it as short as possible. While the statements in PEP 8 are most certainly helpful in programs and projects, I don't think the guidelines hold for minimal example code.

Comment: Well, in a 3 or a 4 line example isn't going to make much odds; I find the clear indentation more readable, and with example code you want to go for maximum readability. :-)